USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener getting implementation error
I'm trying to connect a USB camera using OTG cable. After implementation successful I'm facing an error in implementation method and super type.
public interface OnDeviceConnectListener {
    /**
     * called when device attached
     * @param device
     */
    void onAttach(UsbDevice device);

    /**
     * called when device dettach(after onDisconnect)
     * @param device
     */
    void onDettach(UsbDevice device);

    /**
     * called after device opend
     * @param device
     * @param ctrlBlock
     * @param createNew
     */
    void onConnect(UsbDevice device, UsbControlBlock ctrlBlock, boolean createNew);

    /**
     * called when USB device removed or its power off (this callback is called after device closing)
     * @param device
     * @param ctrlBlock
     */
    void onDisconnect(UsbDevice device, UsbControlBlock ctrlBlock);

    /**
     * called when canceled or could not get permission from user
     * @param device
     */
    void onCancel(UsbDevice device);

    /**
     * Called when USB device is closed
     * @param usbDevice the USB device
     * @param usbControlBlock the USB control block
     */
    void onDeviceClose(UsbDevice usbDevice, UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock);
}

Implementation:
private final USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener mOnDeviceConnectListener = new OnDeviceConnectListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(UsbDevice usbDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:");
        setDefaultUsbDevice();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(UsbDevice usbDevice) {
        setCameraButton(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect(UsbDevice usbDevice, UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock, boolean z) {
        Log.e(TAG, "USB_DEVICE_onConnect:");
        mCameraHandler.open(usbControlBlock);
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDettach(UsbDevice usbDevice) {
        startAgain = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(UsbDevice usbDevice, UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDisconnect:");
        mHasRequest = false;
        if (mCameraHandler != null) {
            queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override // java.lang.Runnable
                public void run() {
                    if (mCameraHandler != null) {
                        mCameraHandler.close();
                    }
                }
            });
            setCameraButton(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceClose(UsbDevice usbDevice, UsbControlBlock usbControlBlock) {
        // Your implementation here
    }
};

My error:
D:\Quality_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\ylp_quality_app\externalcamera\UsbCameraActivity.java:114: error: <anonymous com.ylp_quality_app.externalcamera.UsbCameraActivity$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onDeviceOpen(UsbDevice,UsbControlBlock,boolean) in OnDeviceConnectListener
    private final USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener mOnDeviceConnectListener = new OnDeviceConnectListener() {
                                                                                                              ^
D:\Quality_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\ylp_quality_app\externalcamera\UsbCameraActivity.java:127: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
D:\Quality_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\ylp_quality_app\externalcamera\UsbCameraActivity.java:134: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
D:\Quality_App\android\app\src\main\java\com\ylp_quality_app\externalcamera\UsbCameraActivity.java:139: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

